# What does this Python code does in plain words?

Tags: python

The following is the sample content of the data imported from a file:

```
    X, Y, 80
    Z, W, 100
```

And below is the part of the code that process the content of data from above (which I am trying to understand):

```
    for new in content:
       if new != '\n':
          addIt = new[:-1].split(',') #remove trailing \n
          data.append(addIt)
```

which results on below output of "data" as a list of lists:

```
[['X', 'Y', ' 80'],
 ['Z', 'W', ' 100']]
```

Can someone please explain to me, how the code does what it does in plain English?

Please correct me where I am wrong about my below assumptions on the comments:

```
       for new in content:  #each separate row is taken from the list?
          if new != '\n':   #if "new" does not consist a break of newline?
             addIt = new[:-1].split(',') #splits each row from comma and then what it does with -1?
             data.append(addIt) #this is ok
```

Thank you in advance. It would be much appreciated If you can explain in plain English.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question might not be the best fit for this site. Perhaps review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The code you've provided, for example, won't run. It isn't clear what "content" is so it will be a little hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
addIt = new[:-1].split(',')
```

The first part: `new[:-1]` takes all but the last character from `new`, then `.split(',')` splits the remaining string into a list of items split by the commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
for new in content:
```

Iterate through each line in the file. Each line comes into the variable `new` - the lines have their trailing `\n` attached to them. So they look like: `"X, Y, 80\n" etc.`

```
if new != '\n':
```

If the line is just the newline character, then ignore it. Otherwise process it. Blank lines will be ignored.

```
addIt = new[:-1].split(',')
```

`new[:-1]` is the line - minus the trailing newline `\n` - so this is the content of the line i.e. `"X, Y, 80"`

This is then split by `","` so you get `["X", "Y", "80"]`

```
data.append(addIt)
```

Append this list to the end-result